# Safe way to run multiple async functions in parallel?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm writing some code to scan a directory and it occurred to me this may not be the best idea:

```
files.forEach(async fileName => {
  stat = await lstat(fileName);
});
```

as I'm going to fire off an lstat for every single file in a directory at the same time.  Does anyone know of a "clean" way to do this?  I'm thinking a lib that maintains a queue and drains it.

I know some "old" async libraries do this, but I don't know of anything that do it with native async/await calls

Comment: RxJS may be your friend.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no code does run in parallel so a few hundred open promises shouldn't be a problem.

If you want to run one after another instead a simple for loop will do it :

```
async function iterate(){
 for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
  stat = await lstat(files[i]);
 }
}
```

To run multiple at once, but not all may do so:

```
async function iterate(){
 var atonce=10;
 for(var i=0;i<files.length;i+=atonce){
  stats = await Promise.all(files.slice(i,i+atonce).map(file=>lstat(file));
 }
}
```

Another way would be a few Promise queues:

```
var current=0;
async function retrieve(){
 if(current>=files.length) return;
 current++;
 await lstat(files[current-1]);
 retrieve();
}
retrieve();//two in parallel
retrieve();
```

If you want to run all in parallel, may use Promise.all to catch the results ( depends on the usecase):

```
Promise.all(files.map(async function(file){
 return await lstat(file);
}).then(results=>...);
```

Comment: That does them one at a time.  I'm looking for a middle ground.  Fire 20, then one at a time as they come back.

Comment: @mark kahn whats wrong with multiple async functions at a time?

Comment: you can simplify the second snippet to `Promise.all(files.map(lstat)).then(...)`

Comment: In many situations (perhaps not this one) you can get failures if you fire off too many things at the same time.  Imagine AJAX calls, or DB reads, etc.  Fire off 5 and it's fine.  Fire off 500 and half of them will time out.

Comment: btw, you don't need `Promise.all` to fire them all at the same time, they do that anyway with the code I posted.  You only need `Promise.all` if you want to pull the results out of the inner function, which I don't care about in this case.

Comment: @mark kahn now ive finally got your problem :/ . may run e.g. 10 at once in a loop?

Comment: yeah, I can write it easily enough.  Looking for a solid solution though.  Preferably something with retry thresholds, adjustable queues, timings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
//sry, but I didn't get up with a beter name
function Todo(numParalell = 8){
 var todo = [], running = 0;
  
 function init(resolve){
  if(running < numParalell){
   ++running;
   resolve();
  }else{
   todo.push(resolve);
  }
 }
 
 function next(){
  if(todo.length){
   todo.shift()();  //FIFO
   //todo.pop()();  //LIFO / FILO
  }else{
   --running;
  }
 }
 
 return {
  get numRunning(){ return running },
  get numWaiting(){ return todo.length },
  append(fn){
   if(typeof fn !== "function"){
    //fn ain't a function but a value
    return Promise.resolve(fn);
   }
    
   var promise = new Promise(init).then(fn);
   promise.then(next, next);
   return promise;
  }
 }
}

//a queue that runs 4 tasks in paralell
var todo = Todo(4);

//some task that just kills some time
var someAsyncTask = v => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 5000, v));

//add 25 items to the todo-list 
//and log the start and end time from now
var promises = Array(25).fill(Date.now())
  .map((t,i) => todo.append(() => {
    console.log('+starting', i, 'after', Date.now() - t, 'ms');

    return someAsyncTask()
      .then(() => console.log('-finished', i, 'after', Date.now() - t, 'ms'))
      .then(() => 'resolve to ' + i);
  }));

Promise.all(promises).then(arr => console.log("And the resolved promises:", arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

`Todo#append()` takes a function to perform the async task you want to manage and returns a Promise with the result. Although the function ain't executed immediately, but as soon as there is an empty slot.

Be careful, this code can not resolve dependencies like

```
var todo = Todo(1);
todo.append(() => todo.append(() => ...))
```

so you might get stuck with the outer task no completing, because it depends on/resolves to the inner one. And the inner one might not be able to start, because there is no free slot on this Todo-list.